# Large bowl and small bowl ratio of liquid

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

A large bowl has a radius R and height H

A small bowl has a radius 5/6 R and a height 2/3 H

What is the ratio of liquid in the bowls?

I'm stumped on how to do this one

Comment: Are they a cut out part of a sphere?

Comment: @GoodDeeds the question simply refers to them as bowls full of liquid. I guess you could assume they are a half sphere or part of a sphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume of a bowl is going to be directly proportional to the product of its height and the square of its radius. $$V=kR^2H$$

Replacing $R$ with $\frac{5R}{6}$ and $H$ with $\frac{2H}{3}$ gives a volume of $$V=k(\frac{5R}{6})^2\frac{2H}{3}=\frac{25}{54}kR^2H$$

Therefore, the ratio of the volume of the large bowl to the small bowl is $\frac{54}{25}$.

Comment: Where did you get $V=kR^2H$ from?

Comment: The $k$ comes from direct proportionality and the $R^2H$ comes from using cylindrical coordinates to calculate any volume with radial symmetry.